# React Query define custom behavior if Error (get new Token based on RefreshToken)

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I try to understand how could i override default behavior of React Query if for example i made reguest (query or mutation ) => and it recieved  `401 Unathorization`. I understand that i need to send request to get new access token based on my refresh token which i already have in my localstorage.

I could trigger it every time just write logic if `onError` and then try request once again with new accessToken.

But my app have more than 1000+ requests that i need to add this logic. And i wonder how i can make it in one place by default. Probably in Middleware or something like this (I'm new in React). Please share any kind of suitable solution.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

The recommended approach right now is to *not* couple this logic with react-query, but with the actual library that does the data fetching for you. If you use for example axios - it offers interceptors. There are also some good suggestions in this [discussion about async retries](https://github.com/TanStack/query/discussions/2770).